# How to determine what AMIs are available for a selected AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am currently using cloud formation to launch the following AMI image: ami-0d28e5e0f13248294

However I have been told that the instance type (m5.large) is not supported in my requested Availability Zone (ap-southeast-2a).

How can I find a similar AMI that is supported in ap-southeast-2a. I have tried using the 'launch EC2 instance' in the console but I don't get any information about the availability zones I can use for ap-southeast-2a for my required instance type.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html
There is nothing about AZ.

Comment: AMI's is region specific and not AZ specific.

Comment: The error message seems to be about a given **type of instance** being unavailable in the designated AZ, not about AMIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMI's provide information required to launch the instance. An AMI is registered in a region and not in an availability zone.

You can search the list of AMI's in the given region by the following command

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self amazon --filters "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs"
```